# discord.py how to take user inputs

Tags: python, discord

I tried searching up things but nothing helped me
these are my imports

```
import discord
import typing
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time
```

and this is my code that does not work

```
await ctx.send("Enter the number of matches:")
response = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
try:
    matches = int(response.content)
except:
    print("That's not a number silly")
await ctx.send("Enter the maximum amount that a player can pick:")
response = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
try:
    maxamount = int(response.content)
except:
    print("That's not a number silly")
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are there any errors? What is the expected behaviour?